# Store session in database, is it a good idea?

Tags: php, mysql, session

I'm reading Pro Php Application Performance book

In chapter Sharing Session, the book suggested to store session in database.

It make me curios, is there any performance impact when u store session in database?

I mean database already overloaded with request from dynamic page, and now need to handle session data also.

Now, on every page request, a session data must be read from database.Is it a good idea?

Comment: probably not. i can't imagine this is done for performance reasons.

Comment: @northkildonan so i guess using memcache or redis would be better solution right?

Comment: i don't know much about php performance tweaking. but i can't see native php sessions using/wasting a lot of cpu time.

Comment: @northkildonan this is for web farm, so native php session is out of case unless i configures it to use shared folder.i think i better go with memcache or redis instead..thx for your response

Answer (score 0):

By default, session data is stored in a temporary file somewhere (in `/tmp/...`, make sure it's not visible from the web!). If your site gets a huge amount of traffic and you have an optimized database, or cluster of databases, it might be worth it to store it there.

In your case, you mention that the database is already being strained as it is, so it's probably not worth it.

At any rate, you can take a few minutes to implement the solution of your book, it's not that hard to do. Measure the performance and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Store sessions in database is a good idea when you have to shared session storage for multiple website. If this is not the case, store the session as filesystem is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Storing Session in database is useful when you use multiple app server sharing common DB, and you don't want to put any  custom logic in loadbalancer for redirection of request.
it would be costly operation to hit DB for getting session on every request(unless you cache it).
Anyway, we can always have some logic in loadbalancer to redirect request to appropriate app serverby modifying session cookie.
In your case, it would not be a good idea to have session stored in DB

Answer (score 0):

One advantage of keeping session data in the database is that you can combine it with meta data like user ID, time of login etc. That makes it easy to find out things like *"is user X currently logged in?"*, *"how many users are logged in?"* etc.